# Average previous N occurrences

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to run some Oil Sample analysis in Power BI in which I need an average of the previous three samples for each machine.

I can write a function that averages the samples for a given window using filters, but I need a function that grabs the previous three samples before a specified end date. Basically, I don't want to have to specify a lower bound.

```
Machine  Sample_Date  Interp 
A        1/1/2019     1     
B        1/1/2019     1 
C        1/1/2019     2
A        1/2/2019     1
A        1/3/2019     2      
B        1/3/2019     1 
A        1/4/2019     3      
C        1/4/2019     1 
A        1/5/2019     3      
A        1/6/2019     1 
B        1/6/2019     1      
C        1/6/2019     2
```

I want to take the average of `Interp` for each machine only using the previous three values for each Machine. So `C` would average `(2,1,2)`, `B (1,1,1)` and `A (1,3,3)`.

Comment: Maybe try using `AVERAGEX(TOPN(3,...)...)`.

Comment: would you mind helping me out with what goes in place of the "..."?
I have AVERAGEX(Top(3,Table,Table[Machine]),Table[Interp])
and this doesn't seem to be working

Comment: You know what, I think it is working, it's just rounding.My last concern is how do I know it is using the three Interp from the three most recent dates?

Comment: `TOPN` lets you specify what to order by.

Comment: Thank you. Now with regards to the second part of my question, how do i make it so it takes the previous three based off what my date slider is set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can average over the top 3 by using the [`TOPN` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/topn-function-dax). Note that the third argument lets you specify what column you want to order by.

You can use a `FILTER` function to only consider certain dates. Depending on how your model is done, you may need to do it slightly differently but this may give you an idea:

```
AverageInterp=
AVERAGEX (
    TOPN (
        3,
        FILTER ( Table, Table[Sample_Date] < MAX ( Slicer[Date] ) ),
        Table[Sample_Date]
    ),
    Table[Interp]
)
```

Comment: Okay, I tried this, and it's still using the three most recent dates and doesn't change based on my slider. My slider is from a rolling calendar table. so where you have Slicer[Date] I have Rolling_Calendar[Date].